# Prove simple graph $G$ with even vertices and $d(v_i)>(n/2)$ has 3 perfect matches

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the following result:

Let $G$ a simple graph $n$ vertices, $n$ even, and $d(v) > n/2~\forall v \in V(G)$. Prove that $G$ has three perfect matches two on two disjoint.

I must say I am a bit clueless in this question. I am able do most others questions with not too much trouble.
I thought about doing it by induction in the number of vertices, but I do not think it will work.
I know for example, a $K_4$ works and that it could be my basis for induction, but I cannot find a way build a larger case (n+2) based on the previous (n).

I do not exactly know how to think about a contradiction either.

Comment: sorry what is $g(v)$?

Comment: it is the degree of the vertex. Is this not the usual notation?

Comment: ok, I often see $d(v)$ for degree

Comment: So, here is the argument for it to have a perfect matching(not sure how to show existence of three matchings):

Suppose not, then it has a maximal matching of size $k<\frac{n}{2}$. Then, pick two unmatched vertexes $u,v$ and notice that all edges out of $u,v$ connect to vertices in the matched edges. But by pigeonhole principle, there is a matched edge $cd$ such that $uc$ and $vd$ are edges. But then removing $cd$ and add $uc$ and $vd$ gives a bigger matching , contradiction!!

Does this help?

Comment: @mathpadawan I believe it does help on proving that result. ~However, I was aware of this and could not get anywhere. ~
I think I could try using this strategy to show that it has three but no more than three disjoint perfect matches. EDIT: Actually I did not know that result proof! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Dirac theorem $G$ has a hamiltonian cycles $C$. But $C = M_1 \cup M_2$ where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are disjoint matchings. Now consider the graph $H = G - M_1$. We have $d(v) \gt \frac{n}{2} - 1$ for all $v \in V(H)$ (which means  $d(v) \ge \frac{n}{2}$). Therefore Dirac theorem applies again and $H$ has a hamiltonian cycle $C_2$ which again is the union of two matchings $M_3$ and $M_4$. Thus $M_1$, $M_3$ and $M_4$ are three disjoint matching of $G$